# Run a python script automatically when certain conditions are met

Tags: python

I have a script for web scraping which basically grabs a story (title, description/summary, and the story text) off a website, which often are in multiple pages, and writes it all to a text file.

At the moment, I copy a url and run the python script from PyCharm, it gives the result I need.

But I want to automate the running the script part so that whenever I copy a url containing certain text (e.g. website name), it automatically outputs the text file without me needing to run the script every time I copy a url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any trick to run some code when you just copy some text, but what I would do is to copy and paste the url in a specific text file and have a cron job that runs every minute.

The crone job should be running a python scripts that reads your text file (containing the urls) and starts scraping if any url is in there.

See here for cron job details: https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux

Comment: But would it be possible to start the script, then let it loop forever, and constantly check the clipboard for links and run the scraping part? There might be an obvious answer, but I am a total beginner and this is my first project.